# few selects in one horizontally

Tags: sql

I have few selects from 2 tables of which I want to output horizontal (when running, the number of lines is same), how can I combine them to 1 select horizontally

```
select  * from [Table1] 

select b.ID, count(*) from  [Table2] b
left  join [Table1] a on a.ID=b.ID  
group by b.ID
```

Thanks in advance for the answer

[image]

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Not too familiar with the options to add images and etc, my bad and fixed.

Comment: Actually, it's more prefered to get the sample data as text.  People on SO are answering in their own free time.  And text can be copied&pasted, while text in images can't. Having to type the sample data to test your solution can be annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is bit unclear but if you want to include columns from other table as well just add them to your select list.

```
select b.ID,b.Created,a.ID, count(*) as total from  [Table2] b
left  join [Table1] a on a.ID=b.ID  
group by b.ID,b.Created,a.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select  b1.ID, b1.Date, b2.ID, b2.Date
from [Table1] b1
left join (
  select b.ID, count(*) as "Date" from  [Table2] b
  left  join [Table1] a on a.ID=b.ID  
  group by b.ID
) b2 on b2.ID=b1.ID
```

BTW: It is not smart to use [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for fieldnames.